# How can we detect the region settings from iPhone in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on localizing a Xamarin Forms app now.

In iOS the user can change the Region settings without changing the device language, right? How can we detect this region settings in Xamarin Forms? I tried the following code to get the current culture, but the region setting doesn't do anything to the `CurrentCulture` unless we change the language settings.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

I need to display a decimal value in the app which is supposed to be displayed as 123.456 in US region and 123,456 is France region. I get 123,456 only when I change the language settings.

I can get the current locale using `NSLocale` which gives me **en_FR**. But if I use this to create a new `CultureInfo` it throws `System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException` exception.

```
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en_FR");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [NSLocale.CurrentLocale](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSLocale/).

Also,

> Your application can be notified of changes in the system local by using the NSLocale.CurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification as the notification to monitor with NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Forms. I am not sure how I can use this NSLocale in forms.

Comment: @RamarajT You would need to write a dependency service to access it.

Comment: I have already written the dependency service to read the NSLocale. But the problem is I get en_FR as the locale identifier, and I can't use this to create a forms CultureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late to the party, but in .NET you have to replace the underscore in the culture string.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-FR");
```